# How to delete all occurrences of a specific char in a double linked list?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

Can I know why my code does not work? The logic within the if loops seem to be sound so I believe the error is either in the outer for loop or I am not returning the modified list.

```
struct list* delete_char(struct list* the_list, char value){
    struct list *copy1 = the_list;
    struct list *copy2 = the_list;
    struct list *copy3 = the_list;
    int i = 0;

    for (copy1; copy1 -> info != value; copy1 = copy1 -> next){
        if (copy1 -> info == value){
            copy2 = copy1 -> next;
            copy3 = copy1 -> prev;
            copy3 -> next = copy2;
            copy2 -> prev = copy3;
            i ++;
        }
        if (copy1 -> prev == NULL && copy1 -> info == value){
            copy2 = copy1 -> next;
            copy2 -> prev = NULL;
            i++;
        }
        if (copy1 -> next == NULL && copy1 -> info == value){
            copy2 = copy1 -> prev;
            copy2 -> next = NULL;
            i++;
        }
    }

    if (i == 0){
        printf("The element is not in the list!\n");
    }

    return the_list;
};
```

Comment: you enter the loop only if `node does not contain specific value` and inside the loop you check `if node contains the specific value`.   (`if (copy1 -> info == value)`)

Comment: ^^^^ beyond that. *"the outer for loop"* implies an "inner" loop, of which there is none. There isn't a single `free` call to delete detached nodes (which I also can't find) in this code. We have no [mcve] including your formal structure definition, nor any list population code nor repeatable sample to test against.  This needs some work on your post. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and familiarize yourself with expectations of a posted question. Thanks.

Comment: Create a function to remove a single node. You cannot remove multiple nodes until you can remove a single node.

Answer (score 1):

On first glance I see two issues:

- what is `for (copy1;` supposed to mean? GCC throws a `statement with no effect` warning.
- the first `if` condition inside the loop can never be `TRUE`, because it is the reverse of the loop condition.

If I understand your description correctly you want

- loop over the list
- remove any entry where `info == value`
- print a message when `value` wasn't found in the list
- return the (potentially updated) head of the list

Here is how I would write this function. As your question didn't include the definition for `struct list` I took an educated guess:

```c
struct list {
  char info;
  struct list* prev;
  struct list* next;
};

struct list* delete_char(struct list* the_list, char value) {
  struct list* entry = the_list;
  unsigned int count = 0;

  while (entry) {
    /* entry may be removed during this iteration */
    struct list* next = entry->next;

    if (entry->info == value) {
      struct list* prev = entry->prev;

      /* value found */
      count++;

      /* unchain entry from list */
      if (prev) {
        /* not removing first entry on the list */
        prev->next = next;
      } else {
        /* removing first entry on the list: new head of list */
        the_list = next;
      }
      if (next) {
        /* not removing last entry on the list */
        next->prev = prev;
      }

      /* delete entry */
      free(entry);
      /* NOTE: entry is now invalid! */
    }

    entry = next;
  }

  if (!count) {
    printf("The element is not in the list!\n");
  }

  return the_list;
}
```